# Actual and estimated execution plan in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-execution-plan

I am testing query processing in SQL Server 2008.

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM Student;
```

I checked the estimated query plan and actual query plan. Both look the same. Below is the tool-tip I got for the `Select` node of the actual execution plan. It shows all the estimated values.

How do I find the actual values.

[image]

Comment: @marc_s - yes.I did the same way. Image I have attached is which I got when running query with turned-on execution plan.

Comment: Well, the actual rows returned in not on the `SELECT` node - but on the base operations, like `Clustered Index Scan` or whatever you have

Comment: For number of rows, you inspect the incoming arrow to the select node. Since costs are only something used during optimization, there's no real "Actual" value for those.

Comment: Of course, it's somewhat meaningless - because, if you're running in SSMS, and there's a `SELECT` node at the top of the query, then you can see the actual number of rows by just looking down in the status bar once the query is complete